# Excluding some classes from cobertura report

Tags: code-coverage, gradle, cobertura

I am using a gradle-cobertura plugin for generating test coverage report which can be found [here](https://github.com/valkolovos/gradle_cobertura/wiki). The plugin is working absolutely fine. Now I am trying to exclude some of the classes from the coverage report. I have tried to customize the behavior of the Cobertura plugin by using a closure to configure the convention properties as below:

```
cobertura {
    coverageSourceDirs = sourcesSets.main.groovy.srcDirs
    coverageExcludes = ['class_name.groovy']
}
```

But the coverage report still showing the classes that I have excluded. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks and Regards,
Diganta

Comment: Did you use the fully qualified class name (package + class name) for the exclusion?

Comment: Yes, I have used fully qualified class name.  e.g. lb.web.WebContextListener

Comment: Based on the documentation it looks like you will need to escape the dots e.g. `lb\.web\.WebContextListener`. BTW: I don't think this plugin is maintained anymore. I'd recommend having a look at [another Cobertura plugin](https://github.com/Mapvine/gradle-cobertura-plugin) that is still maintained.

Comment: I have tried the new plugin that you have mentioned. Also tried the configuration options 'ignores' and 'excludes' but, still no results. Any help?

Comment: I'd recommend asking the plugin authors on their GitHub pages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a regular expression.

```
cobertura {
   coverageSourceDirs = sourcesSets.main.groovy.srcDirs
   coverageExcludes = ['.*com\\.myCompany\\.class_name.*']
}
```

The example on the plugin's page shows only a single backslash to escape the dot, but I found I had to use double backslashes (I'm using gradle 1.4).

I will also second the suggestion in the comments to use a newer gradle cobertura plugin - I've had good luck with [this one](https://github.com/stevesaliman/gradle-cobertura-plugin).

Comment: No its not working.I have already tried with the new gradle cobertura plugin you have mentioned. I have also tried with lots of regex, but none of them are giving the desired results :(. I'm using gradle 1.1